# Optimizing over a subset of input variables

Tags: optimization, bayesian-optimization, contextual-bandit

Consider the unconstraint optimization problem:

$$\arg \min_{_0} f(X_0, X_\eta)$$

where

- $X_0$ is the input vector I need to optimize for
- $_\eta$ is a nuisance vector which I do not care about.

This is a contextual bandit problem where the $X_0$ are actions and $X_\eta$ are the contexts.

What I am actually doing is learning the function  from data (e.g. random forest or neural net). After learning the function, I run an optimizer to minimize it.

Due to the nature of my problem, I don't have data incoming in real time, and I have to precompute the optimal actions, across all possible contexts. So I need to somehow integrate or marginalize them.

The reason I want to keep  as input to the predictive model is because it really helps with prediction accuracy.

I am seeking some guidance about how to deal with this nuisance vector. In particular:

- Is this an indication that I am formulating this optimization problem the wrong way?
- Is running the optimization over the full input space {$X_0$, $X_\eta$} and then just selecting only the $X_0$ part a good idea ?
- Is it better to not include $X_\eta$ when training the function $f$ at all, and just deal with the lower accuracy?

or any other feedback or thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Is the minimization done in real time? Do you need a solution that can be used for multiple different $X_\eta$ values? ... Some more context will help!

Comment: It is not real time, and yes the solution should work for multiple $X_\eta$ values.

Comment: I updated my question a little bit, trying to make it more clear